# What is the difference between cube, rollup and groupBy operators?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cube, rollup

I can't find any detailed documentation regarding the differences.

I do notice a difference, because when interchanging `cube` and `groupBy` function calls, I get different results. I noticed that for the result using `cube`, I got a lot of null values on the expressions where I used to use `groupBy`.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

These are not intended to work in the same way. `groupBy` is simply an equivalent of the `GROUP BY` clause in standard SQL. In other words

```scala
table.groupBy($"foo", $"bar")
```

is equivalent to:

```sql
SELECT foo, bar, [agg-expressions] FROM table GROUP BY foo, bar
```

`cube` is equivalent to `CUBE` extension to `GROUP BY`. It takes a list of columns and applies aggregate expressions to *all possible combinations* of the grouping columns. Lets say you have data like this:

```scala
val df = Seq(("foo", 1L), ("foo", 2L), ("bar", 2L), ("bar", 2L)).toDF("x", "y")
```

```scala
df.show

// +---+---+
// |  x|  y|
// +---+---+
// |foo|  1|
// |foo|  2|
// |bar|  2|
// |bar|  2|
// +---+---+
```

and you compute `cube(x, y)` with count as an aggregation:

```scala
df.cube($"x", $"y").count.show

// +----+----+-----+     
// |   x|   y|count|
// +----+----+-----+
// |null|   1|    1|   <- count of records where y = 1
// |null|   2|    3|   <- count of records where y = 2
// | foo|null|    2|   <- count of records where x = foo
// | bar|   2|    2|   <- count of records where x = bar AND y = 2
// | foo|   1|    1|   <- count of records where x = foo AND y = 1
// | foo|   2|    1|   <- count of records where x = foo AND y = 2
// |null|null|    4|   <- total count of records
// | bar|null|    2|   <- count of records where x = bar
// +----+----+-----+
```

A similar function to `cube` is `rollup` which computes hierarchical subtotals from left to right:

```scala
df.rollup($"x", $"y").count.show
// +----+----+-----+
// |   x|   y|count|
// +----+----+-----+
// | foo|null|    2|   <- count where x is fixed to foo
// | bar|   2|    2|   <- count where x is fixed to bar and y is fixed to  2
// | foo|   1|    1|   ...
// | foo|   2|    1|   ...
// |null|null|    4|   <- count where no column is fixed
// | bar|null|    2|   <- count where x is fixed to bar
// +----+----+-----+
```

Just for comparison lets see the result of plain `groupBy`:

```scala
df.groupBy($"x", $"y").count.show

// +---+---+-----+
// |  x|  y|count|
// +---+---+-----+
// |foo|  1|    1|   <- this is identical to x = foo AND y = 1 in CUBE or ROLLUP
// |foo|  2|    1|   <- this is identical to x = foo AND y = 2 in CUBE or ROLLUP
// |bar|  2|    2|   <- this is identical to x = bar AND y = 2 in CUBE or ROLLUP
// +---+---+-----+
```

To summarize:

- When using plain `GROUP BY` every row is included only once in its corresponding summary.
- With `GROUP BY CUBE(..)` every row is included in summary of each combination of levels it represents, wildcards included. Logically, the shown above is equivalent to something like this (assuming we could use `NULL` placeholders):

  ```sql
  SELECT NULL, NULL, COUNT(*) FROM table
  UNION ALL
  SELECT x,    NULL, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY x
  UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL, y,    COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY y
  UNION ALL
  SELECT x,    y,    COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY x, y
  ```
- With `GROUP BY ROLLUP(...)` is similar to `CUBE` but works hierarchically by filling colums from left to right.

  ```sql
  SELECT NULL, NULL, COUNT(*) FROM table
  UNION ALL
  SELECT x,    NULL, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY x
  UNION ALL
  SELECT x,    y,    COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY x, y
  ```

`ROLLUP` and `CUBE` come from data warehousing extensions so if you want to get a better understanding how this works you can also check documentation of your favorite RDMBS. For example PostgreSQL introduced both in 9.5 and [these are relatively well documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS).

Comment: wouldn't there be a `SELECT y,    NULL, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY y` in the `group by rollup` query?

Comment: @Sam, because of `rollup` represents the given list of expressions and all **prefixes** of the list including the empty list, `cube` represents the given list and all of its possible **subsets**.

Answer (score 8):

There's one more member in the "family" which can explain it all - `GROUPING SETS`. We don't have it in PySpark/Scala, but it exists in SQL API.

`GROUPING SETS` is used to design whatever combination of groupings is required. Others (`cube`, `rollup`, `groupBy`) return *predefined existent* combinations:

**`cube("id", "x", "y")`** will return `()`, `(id)`, `(x)`, `(y)`, `(id, x)`, `(id, y)`, `(x, y)`, `(id, x, y)`.
(All the possible existent combinations.)

**`rollup("id", "x", "y")`** will only return `()`, `(id)`, `(id, x)`, `(id, x, y)`.
(Combinations which include the beginning of the provided sequence.)

**`groupBy("id", "x", "y")`** will only return `(id, x, y)` combination.

---

**Examples**

Input df:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("a", "foo", 1),
     ("a", "foo", 2),
     ("a", "bar", 2),
     ("a", "bar", 2)],
    ["id", "x", "y"])
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
```

- **`cube`**

  ```py
  df.cube("id", "x", "y").count()
  ```

  is the same as...

  ```py
  spark.sql("""
      SELECT id, x, y, count(1) count
      FROM df
      GROUP BY 
          GROUPING SETS (
              (),
              (id),
              (x),
              (y),
              (id, x),
              (id, y),
              (x, y),
              (id, x, y)
          )
  """)
  ```

  ```
  +----+----+----+-----+
  |  id|   x|   y|count|
  +----+----+----+-----+
  |null|null|   2|    3|
  |null|null|null|    4|
  |   a|null|   2|    3|
  |   a| foo|null|    2|
  |   a| foo|   1|    1|
  |   a|null|   1|    1|
  |null| foo|null|    2|
  |   a|null|null|    4|
  |null|null|   1|    1|
  |null| foo|   2|    1|
  |null| foo|   1|    1|
  |   a| foo|   2|    1|
  |null| bar|null|    2|
  |null| bar|   2|    2|
  |   a| bar|null|    2|
  |   a| bar|   2|    2|
  +----+----+----+-----+
  ```
- **`rollup`**

  ```py
  df.rollup("id", "x", "y").count()
  ```

  is the same as... `GROUPING SETS ((), (id), (id, x), (id, x, y))`

  ```py
  spark.sql("""
      SELECT id, x, y, count(1) count
      FROM df
      GROUP BY 
          GROUPING SETS (
              (),
              (id),
              --(x),      <- (not used)
              --(y),      <- (not used)
              (id, x),
              --(id, y),  <- (not used)
              --(x, y),   <- (not used)
              (id, x, y)
          )
  """)
  ```

  ```
  +----+----+----+-----+
  |  id|   x|   y|count|
  +----+----+----+-----+
  |null|null|null|    4|
  |   a| foo|null|    2|
  |   a| foo|   1|    1|
  |   a|null|null|    4|
  |   a| foo|   2|    1|
  |   a| bar|null|    2|
  |   a| bar|   2|    2|
  +----+----+----+-----+
  ```
- **`groupBy`**

  ```py
  df.groupBy("id", "x", "y").count()
  ```

  is the same as... `GROUPING SETS ((id, x, y))`

  ```py
  spark.sql("""
      SELECT id, x, y, count(1) count
      FROM df
      GROUP BY 
          GROUPING SETS (
              --(),       <- (not used)
              --(id),     <- (not used)
              --(x),      <- (not used)
              --(y),      <- (not used)
              --(id, x),  <- (not used)
              --(id, y),  <- (not used)
              --(x, y),   <- (not used)
              (id, x, y)
          )
  """)
  ```

  ```
  +---+---+---+-----+
  | id|  x|  y|count|
  +---+---+---+-----+
  |  a|foo|  2|    1|
  |  a|foo|  1|    1|
  |  a|bar|  2|    2|
  +---+---+---+-----+
  ```

---

**Note.** All the above return *existent* combinations. In the example dataframe, there is no row for `"id":"a", "x":"bar", "y":1`. Even `cube` does not return it. In order to get all the possible combinations (existent or not) we should do something like the following (`crossJoin`):

```py
df_cartesian = spark.range(1).toDF('_tmp')
for c in (cols:=["id", "x", "y"]):
    df_cartesian = df_cartesian.crossJoin(df.select(c).distinct())
df_final = (df_cartesian.drop("_tmp")
    .join(df.cube(*cols).count(), cols, 'full')
)
df_final.show()
# +----+----+----+-----+
# |  id|   x|   y|count|
# +----+----+----+-----+
# |null|null|null|    4|
# |null|null|   1|    1|
# |null|null|   2|    3|
# |null| bar|null|    2|
# |null| bar|   2|    2|
# |null| foo|null|    2|
# |null| foo|   1|    1|
# |null| foo|   2|    1|
# |   a|null|null|    4|
# |   a|null|   1|    1|
# |   a|null|   2|    3|
# |   a| bar|null|    2|
# |   a| bar|   1| null|
# |   a| bar|   2|    2|
# |   a| foo|null|    2|
# |   a| foo|   1|    1|
# |   a| foo|   2|    1|
# +----+----+----+-----+
```

Answer (score -2):

1. If you do not want null first remove it using below example
   Dfwithoutnull=df.na.drop("all",seq(col name 1,col name 2))
   Above expression will delete null form the original dataframe

2.group by you know I guess.

3.rollup and cube is GROUPING SET operator.
Roll-up is a multidimensional aggrigation and treating element in hierarchical manner

And in cube rather than treating element hierarchically a cube does the same thing accross all dimension.
You can try grouping_id to understand the level of abstraction