# pyspark dataframe cube method returning duplicate null values

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following data (you can reproduce it by copying and pasting):

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
l = [Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=None), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=None), Row(value=None), Row(value=True), Row(value=None), Row(value=True), Row(value=None), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=None), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=None), Row(value=True), Row(value=None), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=None), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=None), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=None), Row(value=True), Row(value=None), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=None), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=None), Row(value=True), Row(value=None), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=None), Row(value=True), Row(value=None), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=None), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=None), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=None), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=None), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=None), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=None), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=None), Row(value=None), Row(value=None), Row(value=None), Row(value=True), Row(value=None), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=True), Row(value=None), Row(value=None), Row(value=None), Row(value=True), Row(value=None), Row(value=True), Row(value=None)]
l_df = spark.createDataFrame(l)
```

Let's take a look at the schema of `l_df`:

```
l_df.printSchema()

root
|-- value: boolean (nullable = true)
```

Now I want to use `cube()` to count the frequency of each distinct value in the `value` column:

```
l_df.cube("value").count().show()
```

But I see two types of `null` values!

```
+-----+-----+
|value|count|
+-----+-----+
| true|   67|
| null|  100|
| null|   33|
+-----+-----+
```

To verify that I don't actually have two types of `null`:

```
l_df.select("value").distinct().collect()
```

And there is indeed only one type of `null`:

```
[Row(value=None), Row(value=True)]
```

Just to double check:

```
l_df.select("value").distinct().count()
```

And it returns `2`.

I also noticed that `len(l)` is `100` and the first `null` is equal to this number. Why is this happening?

System info: Spark 2.1.0, Python 2.7.8, `[GCC 4.1.2 20070626 (Red Hat 4.1.2-14)] on linux2`

Comment: Don't have my environment available to test ATM but why not just do `l_df.groupBy('value').count().show()`?

Comment: Yeah, that would work. However I still want to figure out why `cube()` doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

These are not two types of nulls but results of different level aggregations. As explained in [What is the difference between cube, rollup and groupBy operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37975227/8371915) your `cube` application is equivalent to:

```
SELECT NULL AS value, COUNT(*) FROM df
UNION ALL
SELECT value, COUNT(*) FROM df GROUP BY value
```

The first query generates tuple `(null, 100)` (total number of records) where `NULL` is just a placeholder, and the second query generates tuples `(true, 67)`, `(null, 33)` where `NULL` is one of the levels of `value` column.

It is easy to check with `grouping` (or `grouping_id`):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import grouping, count

l_df.cube("value").agg(count("*"), grouping("value")).show()
# +-----+--------+---------------+
# |value|count(1)|grouping(value)|
# +-----+--------+---------------+
# | true|      67|              0|
# | null|     100|              1|
# | null|      33|              0|
# +-----+--------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

df.groupBy('value').count().show() will do as @pault said.

In case of cube, adding a "filter" method works for me

```
df.cube("value").count().filter(  col('count')<df.count()  ).show()
```

but an extra process gets added. See the screenhot from my work where I used cube().

[image: See my example]