# Add output of rollup as a new row in a PySpark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am converting sql code into Pyspark.

The sql code is using rollup to sum up the count for each state.

I am try to do the same thing in pyspark, but don't know how to get the total count row.

I have a table with state, city, and count, I want to add a total count for each state at the end of the state sections.

This is a sample input:

```python
State   City      Count
WA      Seattle    10
WA      Tacoma     11
MA      Boston     11
MA      Cambridge  3
MA      Quincy     5
```

This is my desired output:

```python
State   City       Count
 WA     Seattle    10
 WA     Tacoma     11
 WA     Total      21
 MA     Boston     11
 MA     Cambridge  3
 MA     Quincy     5
 MA     Total      19
```

I don't know how to add the total count in between states.

I did try rollup, here is my code:

```python
df2=df.rollup('STATE').count()
```

and the result show up like this:

```python
State  Count
 WA     21
 MA     19
```

But I want the Total after each state.

Comment: Roolup is supported in Spark both in SQL and `DataFrame` API (https://stackoverflow.com/q/37975227/9613318). Did you experience any problems?

Comment: Yes, I did try rollup, but it end up with only state with total count. i want the total count row in between states

Comment: @yokielove it would be helpful if you could share the sql code that you referenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want the `Total` as a new row inside your DataFrame, one option is to union the results of the `groupBy()` and sort by `["State", "City", "Count"]` (to ensure that the `"Total"` row displays last in each group):

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.union(
    df.groupBy("State")\
    .agg(f.sum("Count").alias("Count"))\
    .select("State", f.lit("Total").alias("City"), "Count")
).sort("State", "City", "Count").show()
#+-----+---------+-----+
#|State|     City|Count|
#+-----+---------+-----+
#|   MA|   Boston|   11|
#|   MA|Cambridge|    3|
#|   MA|   Quincy|    5|
#|   MA|    Total|   19|
#|   WA|  Seattle|   10|
#|   WA|   Tacoma|   11|
#|   WA|    Total|   21|
#+-----+---------+-----+
```

Answer (score -2):

Either:

```
df.groubpBy("State", "City").rollup(count("*"))
```

or just register table:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
```

and apply your current SQL query with

```
spark.sql("...")
```

Comment: the first df.groubpBy("State", "City").rollup(count("*")) come back with error: AttributeError: 'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'rollup'

Comment: Shouldn't it be `df.rollup("State", "City").agg(count("*"))`?

Comment: it still not working, the result show up with no total count per state