# Totalize count column with grand total

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I want to add a row with grand total of previously grouped rows.
I have code:

```
df_join = ( 
       df.join(df1, df.serialnumber == df1.entityid)
          .distinct()
         .groupBy("SW_version").count().show(truncate=False)
```

I need to add the grand total row, summing all values in a count column.

For now the result of the code is:

```
 +-----------+-----+
 |SW_version |count|
 +-----------+-----+
 |SG4J000078C|63   |
 |SG4J000092C|670  |
 |SG4J000094C|43227|
 +-----------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rollup` instead of `groupBy` in this case. Rollup will produce one additional row with `null` group and aggregation for all rows.

For `df` like this:

```
+-------+
|version|
+-------+
|      A|
|      A|
|      B|
|      B|
|      B|
|      C|
+-------+
```

`df.rollup("version").count().sort("version", ascending=False).show()` will return:

```
+-------+-----+
|version|count|
+-------+-----+
|      C|    1|
|      B|    3|
|      A|    2|
|   null|    6| <-- this is the grand total
+-------+-----+
```

You can read more about rollup in this post [What is the difference between cube, rollup and groupBy operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37975227/what-is-the-difference-between-cube-rollup-and-groupby-operators/37975484#37975484)

Comment: Tkx you for your help

Comment: @Luuk If the answer was helpful, mark answer as "accepted", please