# Create rows for 0 values when aggregating all combinations of several columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, combinations, aggregation

Using the example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37975227/what-is-the-difference-between-cube-rollup-and-groupby-operators/37975484#37975484), how do I create rows of 0 count when aggregating all possible combinations? When using `cube`, rows of 0 do not populate.

This is the code and output:

```scala
df.cube($"x", $"y").count.show

// +----+----+-----+     
// |   x|   y|count|
// +----+----+-----+
// |null|   1|    1|   <- count of records where y = 1
// |null|   2|    3|   <- count of records where y = 2
// | foo|null|    2|   <- count of records where x = foo
// | bar|   2|    2|   <- count of records where x = bar AND y = 2
// | foo|   1|    1|   <- count of records where x = foo AND y = 1
// | foo|   2|    1|   <- count of records where x = foo AND y = 2
// |null|null|    4|   <- total count of records
// | bar|null|    2|   <- count of records where x = bar
// +----+----+-----+
```

But this is the desired output (added row 4).

```scala
// +----+----+-----+     
// |   x|   y|count|
// +----+----+-----+
// |null|   1|    1|   <- count of records where y = 1
// |null|   2|    3|   <- count of records where y = 2
// | foo|null|    2|   <- count of records where x = foo
// | bar|   1|    0|   <- count of records where x = bar AND y = 1
// | bar|   2|    2|   <- count of records where x = bar AND y = 2
// | foo|   1|    1|   <- count of records where x = foo AND y = 1
// | foo|   2|    1|   <- count of records where x = foo AND y = 2
// |null|null|    4|   <- total count of records
// | bar|null|    2|   <- count of records where x = bar
// +----+----+-----+
```

Is there another function that could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that `crossJoin` here is the correct approach. But I think afterwards it may be a bit more versatile to use a `join` instead of a `union` and `groupBy`. Especially if there are more aggregations than one `count`.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('foo', 1),
     ('foo', 2),
     ('bar', 2),
     ('bar', 2)],
    ['x', 'y'])

df_cartesian = df.select('x').distinct().crossJoin(df.select("y").distinct())
df_cubed = df.cube('x', 'y').count()
df_cubed.join(df_cartesian, ['x', 'y'], 'full').fillna(0, ['count']).show()

# +----+----+-----+
# |   x|   y|count|
# +----+----+-----+
# |null|null|    4|
# |null|   1|    1|
# |null|   2|    3|
# | bar|null|    2|
# | bar|   1|    0|
# | bar|   2|    2|
# | foo|null|    2|
# | foo|   1|    1|
# | foo|   2|    1|
# +----+----+-----+
```

Comment: I agree, utilizing a join provided a more streamlined process. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First, let's see why you do not get combinations that do not appear in your dataset.

> `def cube(col1: String, cols: String*): RelationalGroupedDataset`
>
> Create a multi-dimensional cube for the current Dataset using the specified columns, so we can run aggregation on them. See RelationalGroupedDataset for all the available aggregate functions.

As the doc states it, `cube` is just a fancy group by. You may aslo check that by running `explain` on your result. You would see that `cube` is basically an expand (to obtain the `nulls`) and a group by. Therefore it cannot show you combinations that are not in your dataset. A join would be needed for that so that values that are never in the same record together can "meet".

So let's construct a solution:

```scala
// this contains one line per possible combination, even those who are not in the dataset
// note that we set the count to 0
val cartesian = df
    .select("x").distinct
    .crossJoin(df.select("y").distinct)
    .withColumn("count", lit(0))

// A dataset in which (2, 1) does not exist
val df = Seq((1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)).toDF("x", "y")

// Let's now union the cube with the Cartesian product (CP) and
// reperform a group by.
// Since the counts were set to zero in the CP, this will not impact the
// counts of the cube. It simply adds "missing" values with a count of 0.
df.cube("x", "y").count
    .union(cartesian)
    .groupBy("x", "y")
    .agg(sum('count) as "count")
    .show
```

which yields:

```
+----+----+-----+
|   x|   y|count|
+----+----+-----+
|   2|   2|    1|
|   1|   2|    1|
|   1|   1|    1|
|   2|   1|    0|
|null|null|    3|
|   1|null|    2|
|null|   1|    1|
|null|   2|    2|
|   2|null|    1|
+----+----+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you! A cross join is exactly what I needed. Appreciate your help!